# Ошибка Index out of range. Как исправить?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import Foundation

func inputAndCheckValue() -> Int {
    var tempInput: Int = 0
    var resultParse: Bool = false
    let input = readLine()
    while (!resultParse) {
        resultParse = ((try! Int(input!)) != nil)
        tempInput = Int(input!)!
        if (!resultParse){
            print("ошибка ввода числа задач")}
    }
    return tempInput
}

print("Сколько задач будет протестировано?")
var n = Int(readLine()!)
var N: Int {
    get{
        return n!
    }
    set{
        if (newValue > 1 && (newValue < 10000000)) {
            n = newValue
        }
    }
}
while (N == 0) {
    N = inputAndCheckValue()
    if (N == 0){
        print("число не в заданном диапазоне")}
}
print("Сколько устройств используется?")
var k = Int(readLine()!)
var K: Int {
    get{
        return k!
    }
    set {
        if (newValue > 1 && (newValue < 10000000)) {
            n = newValue
        }
    }
}
while (K == 0) {
    K = inputAndCheckValue()
    if (K == 0){
        print("число не в заданном диапазоне")}
}

var c = [N]
print("Ввод чисел ожидаемого времени")
for i in 0...c.count{
    c[i] = 0
    var checkMass:Bool = false
    while (!checkMass) {
        c[i] = inputAndCheckValue()
        checkMass = true;
        if (c[i] < 1) {
            print("Заданное время меньше минимально возможного")
            checkMass = false;
        }
        if (c[i] > 99) {
            print("Заданное время больше максимально возможного")
            checkMass = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`c.count` возвращает количество элементов в массиве, но так как индексация идет от `0`, то вы пытаетесь работать с элементом, которого в массиве нет.

Правильно будет: `for i in 0...(c.count-1)`

Comment: Тогда уж Half-Open Range Operator так `for i in 0..<c.count`.